# Is my calculation right for differentiability?(with complete resolution if right)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In the following completed example I ask if it is done right.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac {2x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \mbox{for} (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\0 \mbox{for} (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases} $$

Now and the partial derivatives are

$$f^\prime_x= \frac{4xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$and $f^\prime_y= \frac {2x^4-2x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Now we need to see if partial exist on (0,0)

$f^\prime_x= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {2h^2.0/h^2-0}{h}=0$ $f^\prime_y= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {2h^2.0/h^2-0}{h}=0$

Now is the part that I don't know if I can do by choosing paths in the following limit.
$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {f(x,y)-f(0,0)- f^\prime_x Δx - f^\prime_y Δy}{(Δx^2+Δy^2)^(\frac{1}{2})}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}-0-0.Δx-0.Δy}{(x^2+y^2)^(\frac{1}{2})}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^(\frac{3}{2})}$

Now let us choose a path y=x

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {x^3}{(2x^2)^(\frac{3}{2})}= \frac {1}{2^(\frac{3}{2})}$

Now choosing another path y=-x

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {-x^3}{(2x^2)^(\frac{3}{2})}= \frac {-1}{2^( \frac {3}{2})}$

Now I don't know what to concluded but it is obvious that is not diferrenciable?

My questions are can I choose a path on the last limit?and can I do to all limits with more than one variable whatever the limit is?and what is the conclusion I arive on the last limit?

Comment: I'll appreciate any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what do you want conclude. If you want to know if the function are differentiable at the point $(0,0)$ you can proceed like this.

If the function is not continuous, then is not differentiable i.e. you just have to prove that the limit does not exist.

Now, if you want to prove that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$, you must to prove that the Taylor's formula $$f(\vec{a}+h\vec{y})-f(\vec{a}) = \vec{\nabla}f(\vec{a})||\vec{y}||+||\vec{y}||E(\vec{a},\vec{y}).$$

Where $E(\vec{a},\vec{y}) \rightarrow 0$ when $||\vec{y}|| \rightarrow 0$ for any vector $\vec{y}$ such that $h||\vec{y}|| \in B(\vec{a},r)$. That's the definition of a differentiable function at the point $\vec{a}=(a,b).$

Here $h>0$, $r>0$, $E(\vec{a},\vec{y})$ is the error function and $\vec{\nabla}f(\vec{a})=\left( \frac{\partial f(\vec{a})}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f(\vec{a})}{\partial y} \right)$. For this case, $\vec{a}=(0,0)$

Comment: And $B(\vec{a},r)$ is a ball centered at a point $\vec{a}$ and radius $r$

Comment: Oh, one more thing. You can prove if your function is differentiable at the point $\vec{a}$ by proving if your funtion is $\mathcal{C}^1$ i.e. if your function has continuous partial derivatives at the point. But, if your function is not $\mathcal{C}^1$ you can't conclude that your function is not differentiable.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. Its is easy to see that Taylor formula can turn into to an expression that I am familiar to and that I put in the question , I just forget to equal to zero. I realize now that I didn't have to do the second path because the expression wasn't equal to zero for the first path, is this right?

Comment: I want to add also that for a vector function I don't know how do you apply the Taylor formula since the gradient is only define as far I know it to scalar function it has to be the jacobian

Comment: That's right, the jacobian is for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. If you've $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then you've the gradient.