# What is wrong with this proof of continuity of a function of two variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

If a function is define as:

1)$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac {2xy}{x^2+y^2} &\mbox{for} (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\0 &\mbox{for} (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases} $$
Then the following proof argument,

$$\frac {2xy}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac {2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac {2(x^2+y^2)y}{x^2+y^2}=2y$$

As $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$,  $2y=0$

2) $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac {x+y}{x^2+y^2} &\mbox{for} (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\0 &\mbox{for} (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases} $$

$$\frac {x+y}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac {x^2+y|x|}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{x^2|y|+y^2|x|}{x^2+y^2}\leq\ \frac{(x^2+y^2)|y|}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{(x^2+y^2)|x|}{x^2+y^2}=|x|+|y|$$

As $(x,y)  \rightarrow  (0,0)$, $|x|+|y|=0$.

I have seen that 1) was not continuous somewhere and I almost positive that I seen that for 2) but I arrive to conclusion that both are continuous.

What is wrong with this proof? or are they in fact continuous? If so, is this a rigorous proof for continuity?

Comment: In 1) you assume $x\geq 1$ when stating $\frac{2xy}{\ldots} \leq \frac{2x^2y}{\ldots}$. Thus this argument does not hold when taking the limit $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. Same goes for 2). For both 1) and 2) the limit does not exist so the function(s) are not continous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Proof is the noun, prove is the verb.

Comment: For the very first inequality let x and y be positive and x<1. You will see that the inequality doesnt hold. Exactly the same problem occurs at the first inequality of your second question.

Comment: $x\leq x^2$ if and only if $x\geq 1$.

Comment: So what method I use to prove discontinuity? Can you give me a hint? And why this works for a function like $\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ for $\ (x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and 0 for (x,y)=(0,0). I know that x>x^2 for 0<x<1 but I multiply with x for 1) and x and y for 2)  @Winther

Comment: Can you comment my comment above @ThePortakal

Comment: Can you comment my comment above @idm

Comment: Can you comment my comment above @PedroTamaroff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, if $$\lim\limits_{(x,0)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,0)=\lim\limits_{(x,0)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{2x.0}{x^2+0^2}=0.$$

But $$\lim\limits_{(x,x)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,x)=\lim\limits_{(x,x)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{2x^2}{x^2+x^2}=\lim\limits_{(x,x)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{2x^2}{2x^2}=1.$$

This implies that if we approach to the point $(0,0)$ from the direction of the line $y=0$ we have a different limit value that the direction of the line $y=x$. Thus, the limit does not exist.

Comment: Can you answer to a previous question that I made?it could be simple as saying yes. Not sure if I done is right.I have taking a path to test differentiability,and that I am not sure I can do.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920680/is-my-calculation-right-for-differentiabilitywith-complete-resolution-if-right @Jeremy

Comment: By the way thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

To prove that your functions are discontinous at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ switch to polar coordinates

$$(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$

For function 1) we get

$$f_1(x) = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} = 2\cos\theta\sin\theta$$

Now take the limit $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along any line $y = (\tan\theta) x$ that is $r\to 0$ with $\theta = $ constant. Note that if the limit exists then it has to give the same result no matter how you approach $(0,0)$. The same method can be used for function 2).

Comment: It is obvious that r must go to zero but by why you have choose $y=\tan\theta$. And how do I translate that into limits from (x,y) $\rightarrow$(0,0) to (r, $\theta$ ) $\rightarrow$ (?,?) Or even chosee a path

Comment: @KellyBlunie This is just a useful way to show that the limit cannot exist (it cannot be used to show that the limit exist btw). Choose two different $\theta_1,\theta_2$ and take the limit along these lines. For the first line you get $L_1 = \lim_{r\to 0,\theta=\theta_1}f_1(x) = 2\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1$ and for the second line you get $L_2 = \lim_{r\to 0,\theta=\theta_2}f_1(x) = 2\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2$. If the limit is to exist then we must have $L_1 = L_2 = 0$. But clearly this is not the case when $\theta_1 \not =\theta_2 \not = 0$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: For the question why $y= x \tan\theta$: If $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ then  $\frac{y}{x} = \tan\theta$. The reason I want to keep $\theta$ constant is to have a simple way of taking the limit in two different ways to show that the limit cannot exist. A simpler way (if you want to avoid polar-coordinates) is to just try taking the limit directly along different curves $y = kx$ for different $k$ values. If the result depends on $k$ then the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you for  your comments it became clear to me @winther

Comment: Can you answer to a previous question that I made?it could be simple as saying yes. Not sure if I done is right.I have taking a path to test differentiability,and that I am not sure I can do. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920680/is-my-calculation-right-for-differentiabilitywith-complete-resolution-if-right @winther